# How to get the right approximation for a series involving the harmonic number?

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation

The right numerical value of the closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^n H_n^2}{{2n\choose n}n^2}$ is $40.66752074791188333...$.

I tried to verify this result on Mathematica using the command:

```
NSum[4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2), {n, 1, Infinity},
     WorkingPrecision -> 8]
```

but it failed to give any approximation, so I replaced `Infinity` by `1000 000` and it gave 39.70 which is close to the numeric value of the closed form. My question is: why Mathemtica fails to give the right approximation for series involving the binomial series when we use `Infinity`?. Other question is: is there another command besides

```
NSum[4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2), {n, 1, 1000000}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 8]
```

that gives a more accurate approximation?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Are you sure about the right numerical value? Because I find $40.66752074791188\ldots$

Comment: I get the same as @Roman

Comment: @Roman thank you. Yes the value you mentioned is the right one. I edited my post. I would like to know the command you used.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thank you Michael. Whats the command you used and gave you 40.66...?

Comment: I did pretty much the same thing as @MichaelE2, it's standard practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terms in the asymptotic expansion of the summand may be summed symbolically and thereby determine the major component of the desired sum.  This helps `NSum` deal with the remainder. I'm not an expert on numerical summation, and I know neither why the sum is numerically difficult (other than convergence is very slow) nor what better methods/transformations might be applied (even if the method is not available in `NSum`).  This approach worked, so I didn't go looking for other ways to accelerate convergence.

The `majorsum` converges very slowly toward the desired sum, but increasing the `order` improves the ability of `NSum` to deal with the remainder.  Both `Sum` and `NSum` take a few seconds to run.

```
order = 12;
major = Normal@Series[
    4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2),
    {n, Infinity, order}];
majorsum = Sum[major, {n, Infinity}];

majorsum + NSum[
  4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2) - major,
  {n, 1, Infinity},
  NSumTerms -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> "WynnEpsilon"]

(*  40.66752074791188333784746413477  *)
```

Comment: Amazing. thank you very much.+1

Comment: whats `order=12` and `NSumTerms-> 50` stand for? and does `50` in `NSumTerms`  and `WorkingPrecision` has to be the same?

Comment: They are described in the docs. `Sum[expr, {n, Infinity, order}]` gives a series of order `order`.  The others are described in `NSum`.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I compared your command to approximate the zeta(6) with `N[Zeta[6],100]` and the error was zero. Interesting!

Comment: @AliShadhar Oops, *`Series[expr, {n, Infinity, order}]`, not `Sum[...]`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat different way. First, we approximate the summand for big `n`. Second, we *exactlly* summarize that approximated summand from `20` to `Infinity`. Third, we add the first 19 terms.

```
Normal[Series[4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n]* n^2),{n, Infinity,20}]];
Sum[%, {n, 20, Infinity}];
N[%, 20] + Sum[4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2), {n, 1, 19}]
```

> `40.667520747911883338`

Comment: Beautiful command. thank you .+1

Comment: BTW, the error can be estimated here. The one is of order $20^{-18}$ at first sight.

Comment: Can you give more digits for approximation ?

Comment: @AliShadhar: Let us change the last two lines by `Sum[%, {n, 25, Infinity}];
N[%, 42] + 
 Sum[4^n HarmonicNumber[n]^2/(Binomial[2 n, n] n^2), {n, 1, 24}]`. This produces `40.6675207479118833378474641375573196174775`. In most cases such precision is not needed.