# AsymptoticSum does not give any output

Tags: series-expansion, asymptotics

I am trying to get leading terms in terms of $p$ of the following expression $\sum_{j = p+2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\Pi_{n=2}^{j} (1+(0.75/n)) }}{\sqrt{j}(1+j)} $. I know that this sum converges and is finite (verified empirically).

In Mathematica, I tried the following expression but the output is same as the input.

```
AsymptoticSum[
 Sqrt[Product[1 + (0.75/n), {n, 2, j}]]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, p + 2, 
  k}, {k, Infinity, 3}]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about analytically evaluating the product

```
Product[1 + (3/(4 n)), {n, 2, j}]
```

$$\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{7}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right) \Gamma (j+1)}$$

and expanding the series terms at infinity

```
Sum[Series[
   Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4] Gamma[1 + j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)),
  {j, Infinity, 3}] // Normal, 
{j, p + 2, Infinity}]
```

$$\frac{64 \zeta \left(\frac{9}{8},p+2\right)-43 \zeta \left(\frac{17}{8},p+2\right)}{64 \sqrt{\Gamma \left(\frac{11}{4}\right)}}$$

Comment: Sorry, this is not it: even for big `p` "expanding the series terms at infinity", you calculate a sum which differs from the given one. No estimates and nimeric examples of this difference are given by you.

Comment: @user64494 - your comparison was mistakenly done using machine precision. Compare `NSum[Sqrt[Product[1 + (3/4/n), {n, 2, j}]]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, 10 + 2, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` with `Sum[Series[Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4] Gamma[1 + j])]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, Infinity, 3}] // Normal, {j, 10 + 2, 1000}] // N[#, 30] & // Quiet`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you for your attempt  of shedding light on the numerical results. Without `Quiet` we see an error "General::ivar: 13 is not a valid variable." .Unfortunately, many comments in this thread are delited without any explanation.

Comment: `N[(64 HurwitzZeta[9/8, 2 + p] - 
     43 HurwitzZeta[17/8, 2 + p])/(64 Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]]) /. 
  p -> 10, 30]` produces `4.61812370467188978210567709113`, whereas `N[(64 HurwitzZeta[9/8, 2 + p] - 
     43 HurwitzZeta[17/8, 2 + p])/(64 Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]]) /. 
  p -> 10, 30]` results in `1.959537023723182441105`. How to explain the difference?

Comment: @user64494 - the two expressions given in your comment for comparison are identical and naturally return identical results. Perhaps you pasted in something other than what you intended.

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you. It should be @`NSum[Sqrt[Product[1 + (3/4/n), {n, 2, j}]]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, 
  10 + 2, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` produces `1.959537023723182441105` wheraeas `N[(64 HurwitzZeta[9/8, 2 + p] -       43 HurwitzZeta[17/8, 2 + p])/(64 Sqrt[Gamma[11/4]]) /.    p -> 10, 30] ` results in `4.61812370467188978210567709113`" in my previous comment. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: @user64494 - I suspect the problem is that the proposed result is only valid for very large `p`; consequently, the numeric sum cannot be evaluated with a fixed upper bound such as `{j, p+2, 1000}`since the lower bound would exceed the upper bound for large `p`. The upper bound of the iterator would also have to depend on `p` or at least be (much?) larger than any `p` considered.

Comment: @BobHanlon True, the expression under the sum goes as $\frac1{j^{9/8}}$ for large $j$. But we know that $\frac1{j}$ diverging. So indeed, it is very slowly converging sequence. $1000\neq \infty$!

Comment: @yarchik: Indeed, `NSum[Sqrt[Product[1 + (3/4/n), {n, 2, j}]]/(Sqrt[j]*(j + 1)), {j, 
  10 + 2, 1500000}]` results in `3.55296`  and `NSum[Series[
   Sqrt[Gamma[7/4 + j]/(Gamma[11/4] Gamma[1 + j])]/(Sqrt[
       j]*(j + 1)), {j, Infinity, 3}] // Normal, {j, 1000001, 
  Infinity}]` performs `1.12176`. Therefore, `4.61812370467188978210567709113`  seems to be  a reasonable result. Of course, this is a numerical example, no more and no less.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a variation on [the theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240808/how-to-get-the-right-approximation-for-a-series-involving-the-harmonic-number/240813#240813).